# Could firestore security rule allows me to change request data or already existing data ?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

To say that I want to increase counter every new document added.
Something similar to  this :

```
request.source.data.i_counter = 1;
getAfter(...).data.i_counter = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase security rules can only ensure the user is authorized to read/write the data they're accessing, and that the data follows the format you've coded for it. Security rules cannot change the data that is being written, nor change the data that is being read.